# PHP Multidimensional array - do I need this key or not?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am creating my first associative multidimensional array in php and I am wondering about a key - whether to use it or not.  I'm creating a form where a user inputs a food name.  when they submit the form, the php handler will search through my multidimensional array, see if there's a match, and if so, display the data associated with that food.

In table form, it's easy:

NAME  /  VALUE  /  ADD'L INFO  /   NUTRITIONAL INFO
Apples /  Yes  /  good for you  /    Calories: 57
                                   serving size: 1 cup (etc - many values here)

So I think I have two choices:

```
//first possible choice
$yesorno = array( 
               array( Name => "apples", 
                      Value => "yes",
                      Addinfo => 15 
                      nutrinfo => array (
                                                           "Serving Size" => "1 cup sliced",
                                                           "Calories" => 57,
                                                           "Carbohydrates" => "15 g",
                                                           "Total Fat" => "0.2 g",
                                                           "Saturated Fat" =>  "0 g",
                                                           "Fiber" =>  "2.6 g",
                                                           "Protein" => "0.3 g" ,
                                                           "Vitamin A" => "59 IU",
                                                           "Vitamin C" => "5 mg", 
                                                           "Vitamin B6" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin B12" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin D" => 0,
                                                           "Calcium" => "7 mg",
                                                           "Magnesium" => "5 mg",
                                                           "Iron" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Potassium" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Sodium" => "1 mg"
                                                          ),
                    ),
               array( Name => "bananas", 
                      Value => "yes",
                      Addinfo => 25,
                    ),
               array( Name => "cauliflower", 
                      Value => "yes",
                      Addinfo => 7 
                    )
             );
```

OR THIS:

```
$yesorno = array ( 
                  "apples"  => array (  
                                       "name" => "apples",  
                                       "value" => "Yes",  
                                       "addinfo" => "", 
                                       "nutrinfo" => array (
                                                           "Serving Size" => "1 cup sliced",
                                                           "Calories" => 57,
                                                           "Carbohydrates" => "15 g",
                                                           "Total Fat" => "0.2 g",
                                                           "Saturated Fat" =>  "0 g",
                                                           "Fiber" =>  "2.6 g",
                                                           "Protein" => "0.3 g" ,
                                                           "Vitamin A" => "59 IU",
                                                           "Vitamin C" => "5 mg", 
                                                           "Vitamin B6" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin B12" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin D" => 0,
                                                           "Calcium" => "7 mg",
                                                           "Magnesium" => "5 mg",
                                                           "Iron" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Potassium" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Sodium" => "1 mg"
                                                          ),
                                       ), 
                  "bananas"  => array ( 
                                       "name" => "bananas",  
                                       "value" => "yes",  
                                       "addinfo" => "",
                                       "nutrinfo" => array (
                                                           "Serving Size" => "1 cup sliced",
                                                           "Calories" => 57,
                                                           "Carbohydrates" => "15 g",
                                                           "Total Fat" => "0.2 g",
                                                           "Saturated Fat" =>  "0 g",
                                                           "Fiber" =>  "2.6 g",
                                                           "Protein" => "0.3 g" ,
                                                           "Vitamin A" => "59 IU",
                                                           "Vitamin C" => "5 mg", 
                                                           "Vitamin B6" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin B12" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin D" => 0,
                                                           "Calcium" => "7 mg",
                                                           "Magnesium" => "5 mg",
                                                           "Iron" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Potassium" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Sodium" => "1 mg"
                                                          ),
                                       ), 

                  );
```

So I'm wondering about the difference between option 1 and option 2 - the difference being that option 2 has a key for the 2nd array where the first one doesn't.  I will search for name and then retrieve name, value, additional info, and nutritional info (which contains many values).

Is it better to use the key in option 2 or not use it as in option 1? It seems redundant to have "apples"/"bananas", etc. twice.  If I use the key, will that present a problem when I go to search thru the arrays looking for "apples" or whatever food name the person inputs on the form, since the same name is listed twice?

Also, do you really need quotation marks around the key (e.g., "name") or is that optional?

Comment: Do you want get value of key(name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use later form of array declaration , as there is no confusion or conflicts to pick the elements with that associated key, if you want to create any array that uses key to identify apples in this example, you can create an array like below, so it will resolve you conflicts.

```
$yesorno = array ( 'apples'=>array(
                                 'applename'=>array(
                                       "value" => "Yes",  
                                       "addinfo" => "", 
                                       "nutrinfo" => array (
                                                           "Serving Size" => "1 cup sliced",
                                                           "Calories" => 57,
                                                           "Carbohydrates" => "15 g",
                                                           "Total Fat" => "0.2 g",
                                                           "Saturated Fat" =>  "0 g",
                                                           "Fiber" =>  "2.6 g",
                                                           "Protein" => "0.3 g" ,
                                                           "Vitamin A" => "59 IU",
                                                           "Vitamin C" => "5 mg", 
                                                           "Vitamin B6" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin B12" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin D" => 0,
                                                           "Calcium" => "7 mg",
                                                           "Magnesium" => "5 mg",
                                                           "Iron" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Potassium" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Sodium" => "1 mg"
                                                          ),
                                                    ),
                                 'applename2'=>array(
                                       "value" => "Yes",  
                                       "addinfo" => "", 
                                       "nutrinfo" => array (
                                                           "Serving Size" => "1 cup sliced",
                                                           "Calories" => 57,
                                                           "Carbohydrates" => "15 g",
                                                           "Total Fat" => "0.2 g",
                                                           "Saturated Fat" =>  "0 g",
                                                           "Fiber" =>  "2.6 g",
                                                           "Protein" => "0.3 g" ,
                                                           "Vitamin A" => "59 IU",
                                                           "Vitamin C" => "5 mg", 
                                                           "Vitamin B6" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin B12" => 0,
                                                           "Vitamin D" => 0,
                                                           "Calcium" => "7 mg",
                                                           "Magnesium" => "5 mg",
                                                           "Iron" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Potassium" => "0.1 mg",
                                                           "Sodium" => "1 mg"
                                                          ),
                                                     ),
                                  )
                   );
```

if i understood your question well, then i hope this will give u the solution.And the quotes for the key is necessary , because if you assign a value the parser will consider it as a variable and produces an error the variable is not found error. thank you.